# sscanf make strange return in C99

Tags: scanf, c99

I normally have no problem to use sscanf but in that case I am lost. Can somebody help me?

```
char pcStr[12] = {"+CVTER: 6,1\0"};

uint32_t aa,bb;

sscanf(pcStr, "%*[^:] %*2c %zu[^,] %*c %zu", &aa, &bb);
```

aa = 6 which is ok

bb = undefined value should be 1.

Why is it so?

Comment: What does sscanf() return? If it's not 2, then bb was not assigned to.

Comment: sscanf() returns 1 instead of 2 aa is correctly filled with 6 but bb = 0

Comment: That should tell you that your format string is not doing what you think it is doing.

Answer (score 0):

The `[^,]` matches the four literal characters. Did you mean to use `%*[^,]` instead?

Comment: %zu is matching the uint32_t type so %zu[^,] will tells sscanf to get uint32_t until ',' caracter.

Comment: @Delphes No. `%zu` matches a `size_t`, which may not be a `uint32_t`. The following `[^,]` matches the characters `[`, `^`, `,` and `]` because there's no introductory `%[` to go with it.

Comment: so how to match uint32_t if not %zu ?

Comment: Either use size_t instead of uint32_t to declare aa and bb, or use the scanf format specifier for uint32_t, which is the macro `SCNu32`.